# How to convert the raw image byte array to PNG image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

I have a raw image (in .raw format without any image header), which I want to convert to PNG format to display on canvas. I tried to convert the raw image to RGBA and it was successful(by manipulating the bytes and using `ImageData` API in canvas). Now I need to convert the raw image to PNG.

I tried by,

1. Fetching the image and create array buffer from the response
2. create UInt8Array of the image `arraybuffer` created.
3. convert it to `base64:png` content

Could anyone help me please?

I have tried multiple solutions found on internet, but none of them works for me.

1. Creating a blob and using it construct an Object URL and display on canvas - Not worked
2. Adding PNG image header to byte array and display on canvas.

   ```
   fetch(image.src).then(resp => {  // load from original source
     return resp.arrayBuffer();
     //return resp.blob();      // obtain a blob
   }).then(arrayBuffer => {
     let int8array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
     let base64content = this.arrayBufferToBase64(int8array.buffer);
     let newImg = document.createElement('img');
     newImg.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64content;
     this.context.drawImage(newImg, 0, 0);
   });

   arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
   let binary = '';
   let bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
   var len = bytes.byteLength;
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
   }
   return window.btoa( binary );
   }
   ```

   I would expect a png image drawn on canvas as the result, but I am seeing empty canvas.
3. I also tried by adding the PNG image header directly to the `bytearray` content of image

```
    fetch(image.src).then(resp => {
          return resp.arrayBuffer();
        }).then(arrayBuffer => {
          let int8array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
          let signature = new Uint8Array([137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]);
          let newArray = new Uint8Array(int8array.length + signature.length);
          newArray.set(signature);
          newArray.set(int8array, signature.length);
          const imgData = this.uint8ToImageData(newArray, 500, 500);
          this.context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
     });
     uint8ToImageData(uint8, width, height) {
          let iData = this.context.createImageData(width, height);
          for (let i = 0; i < uint8.length; i++) {
            iData.data[i] = uint8[i];
          }
          return iData;
      }
```

I could atleast see an image displayed on canvas, but different than the original one.

Comment: How is the image different to the original?

Comment: The pixels seems to have different values, so the appearance look with different color, but with same traces of original image.

Comment: Ok, but if you use the code I posted does that give you the PNG data url, even if it doesn't work? If so, the problem is just a matter of debugging your code. If you edit to include a screenshot of both the original and the canvas version, that might make it easier.

Comment: Yeah, I could see the PNG data URL with your code. Regarding the screenshots, I could not post it here as it is strictly internal to my company.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. In your code in #3 though, I find it odd that you're adding the PNG signature to the raw image data before using `putImageData`, because what you're actually doing is drawing 2 pixels (4 bytes/pixel) of the PNG signature to the canvas, and then misaligning the rest of the image. I would start by removing the signature, as you're not writing to an actual PNG file but rather a canvas.

Comment: ok. even if I remove the signature I still see the same image on canvas which is different than the actual one on color scheme. May be because the RGB values are corrected by the browser before drawing it on canvas?

Comment: If the colour are off, not just pixels being misaligned, then clearly there is a problem with either the data itself or more likely how it is decoded. If you can, I would `console.log(arrayBuffer)` and compare the values in that to the actual pixel values of the image (using an image editor to find them). If they're the same, then perhaps the raw data does not have alpha encoded? If it doesn't have alpha, your program will map RGBRGB... to RGBARG... which could be causing the color issues. To fix this you could simply edit `uint8ToImageData` to set every 4th channel to 255.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try it out and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image in an RGBA array format and you can print it to the canvas, you can simply use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get a PNG string like `"data:image/png;base64,ABCDEFG..."`

The only limitation I know of with `canvas.toDataURL` is that if you have loaded an image from another site directly the canvas (ie via `ctx.drawImage`) it will put the canvas into a 'broken' state so that you cannot access the image (this may only apply accessing the `ImageData` API though). However, if you remotely load the raw image data and use the `ImageData` API I do not think it will be triggered, so the following example should work:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 150;

ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillText('Testing', canvas.width/2 - 20, canvas.height/2);

document.getElementById('dump').innerText = canvas.toDataURL();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<p>As you can see the textarea has the PNG data url of the canvas</p>
<textarea id='dump'></textarea>
```

Comment: But I have the image in raw format locally. I tried converting it to base64content using the function in my code on original question. Also I have already tried by using the URL.createObjectURL() method after creating a blob with the image data and draw it on canvas. But both approaches did not give an ouput.

Comment: @Arun, sorry, I read `"I tried to convert the raw image to RGBA and it was successful(by manipulating the bytes and using ImageData API in canvas). Now I need to convert the raw image to PNG"` and thought you meant you had managed to draw the image to the canvas using ImageData and just needed to convert the canvas to a PNG.