# How can I convert raw pixel data to base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, pixel

I want to load raw pixel data and convert it into base64 data image.

For example I have a matrix with this structure:

```
[[0, 0, 124, 255, ....], ....]
```

And I want to convert it to base64 with this structure:

```
"data:image/webp;base64,AA...."
```

Right now I'm using sharp, like that:

```
sharp(Buffer.from(data), {
        raw: {
          width: displayWidth,
          height: displayHeight,
          channels: 1,
        },
      })
        .webp({ quality: 100 })
        .toBuffer()
        .then((data) => {
          const base64 = `data:image/webp;base64,${data.toString("base64")}`;
          const img = base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
          scanImageStore.setImage(base64);
          console.timeEnd(`image-${id}`);
        });
```

but it works very slow (around 500ms per conversion). I'm searching for a faster way to do so because the image getting loaded alot of times in a short duration.

Comment: To start with a webp file isn't a matrix, it's a linear sequence of data so you have to first convert the matrix to a linear buffer and then it's trivial to convert that to base64.  Of course, if you intend for it to be interpreted as a webp image, you have to make sure the datra is in that format not just random binary data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768710/how-to-convert-the-raw-image-byte-array-to-png-image-using-javascript